# NHibernate: cannot append items to map element

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary, mapping

I have map element in my mapping -

```
        <component name="Resources">
        <map name="Inner" table="SomeTable" lazy="false" fetch="join" access="field.lowercase-underscore">
            <key column="Id"/>
            <index column="IndexId" type="String"/>
            <composite-element class="SomeResource">
                <property name="Name"/>
            </composite-element>
        </map>
        </component>
```

I want to append items in the SomeTable in the following way -

```
            var ent = new Entity();
        ent.Resources.Add("key1", new SomeResource());

        var saved = Session.SaveOrUpdate(ent);
        Session.Session.Flush();
        Session.Session.Clear();

        var newEntity = new Entity {Id = saved.Id};
        ent.Resources.Add("key2", new SomeResource());

        Session.SaveOrUpdate(newEntity);  // here nHib generates DELETE FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = saved.Id
        Session.Session.Flush();
        Session.Session.Clear();
```

I want to have elements "key1" & "key2" in the SomeTable after the run, how can this be done?.. Currently nHib deletes all elements with the specified id from the SomeTable before second save.

Answer (score 1):

With this code you are creating two elements with the same id, that is a primary key: that's why NHibernate deletes the element "key1" (the ent object).

When you create newEntity, don't assing Id property (as you do with ent) if you want a completely new object. Otherwise, if you want to update an existing object, you do:

```
    var ent = new Entity();
    ent.Resources.Add("key1", new SomeResource());

    var saved = Session.SaveOrUpdate(ent);
    Session.Session.Flush();
    Session.Session.Clear();

    // later...

    var entToUpdate = Session.Get<Entity>(saved.Id);
    ent.Resources.Add("key2", new SomeResource());

    Session.SaveOrUpdate(entToUpdate);
    Session.Session.Flush();
    Session.Session.Clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I don't want a completely new entity, i just want to add a new item to an inner map collection of the existing entity.

Comment: then why do you create a newEntity? you just add the new item to "ent" object.

Comment: Well, I can't ). I simplified a lot the example above, in my application I don't have "ent" object..

Comment: I updated the code, but if you want to reference to a particular object you need to know, somehow, its ID.

Comment: Thanks! Can it be done without re-reading entity from the db?

Comment: If you have "ent", use it. If you don't - as you write in your previous comment - you have to read it from the db.